# Stacking Multiple Arrays In Query/Lambda Function

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, import, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

My question was inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74267193/11732320) in that I'm wondering if it's possible to create a formula to stack a dynamic amount of arrays based on a list (see below for clarification).

### Sample Starting Data From Three Sources

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| India | 9 |
| Delta | 4 |
| Hotel | 8 |

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Alpha | 1 |
| Echo | 5 |
| Foxtrot | 6 |

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Bravo | 2 |
| Gulf | 7 |
| Charlie | 3 |

### Desired final result:

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Alpha | 1 |
| Bravo | 2 |
| Charlie | 3 |
| Delta | 4 |
| Echo | 5 |
| Foxtrot | 6 |
| Gulf | 7 |
| Hotel | 8 |
| India | 9 |

I can get the final result by using a query function as shown [in this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ovuh1bpjAQWp5b_J3wuNclkt0ycBXpYsEMXQi4e35YA/edit?usp=sharing) with a formula referencing the appropriate cells with `fileID` and `range`:

```
=Query({IMPORTRANGE(E2,F2);
    IMPORTRANGE(E3,F3);
     IMPORTRANGE(E4,F4)},"Select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1",1)
```

if you want to play with it in your own sheet, you could use this hard-coded function which is the same as above:

```
=Query({IMPORTRANGE("1WtI56_9mhyArMn_j_H4pZg8E0QdIBaKoJfAr-fDAoE0","'Sheet1'!A:B");
    IMPORTRANGE("1HamomAuLtwKJiFEtRKTuEkt--YDTtWChUavetBcAcBA","'Sheet1'!A2:B");
     IMPORTRANGE("1WtI56_9mhyArMn_j_H4pZg8E0QdIBaKoJfAr-fDAoE0","'Sheet2'!A2:B")},"Select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1",1)
```

[image]

### My Question:

Is there a way to leverage a formula to generate this result based on the number of file ids and ranges in columns `E` and `F`? So if a fourth `ID` and range were added, the desired result in columns `a` and `b` would be shown? I suspect Lambda would work, but I am not as strong with it as I should be.

**Unsuccessful attempt:**

`=lambda(someIDs,SomeRanges,IMPORTRANGE(someIds,SomeRanges))(filter(E2:E,E2:E<>""),filter(F2:F,F2:F<>""))`

***REALLY* Bad Attempts:**

`=contact(Player()*1800-CoffeeBribe*Not(Home))`

`=company(theMaster(emailed)*(false))<>`

All helpful answers will be upvoted if not accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Can I answer with Im here for the up-v*te? @pgSystemTester :D

Comment: I think that would be stretching the definition of *helpful answers* =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if ranges would be the same:

```
=LAMBDA(x, QUERY(REDUCE({"ID", "Amount"}, x, 
 LAMBDA(a, c, {a; IMPORTRANGE(c, "Sheet1!A2:B")})), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 1))
 (E2:INDEX(E:E, MAX((E:E<>"")*ROW(E:E))))
```

[image]

---

if ranges are not the same:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, y, QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(MAP(x, y, 
 LAMBDA(e, f, QUERY("♣"&FLATTEN(QUERY("♥"&TRANSPOSE(
 IMPORTRANGE(e, f)),,9^9)),,9^9))),,9^9), 
 "♣")), "♥"), "where Col1 <> ' ' order by Col2", 1))(
 E2:INDEX(E:E, MAX((E:E<>"")*ROW(E:E))), 
 F2:INDEX(F:F, MAX((F:F<>"")*ROW(F:F)))))
```

[image]

or:

```
=LAMBDA(x, QUERY(REDUCE({"ID", "Amount"}, x, 
 LAMBDA(a, b, {a; IMPORTRANGE(b, OFFSET(b,,1))})), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 1))
 (E2:INDEX(E:E, MAX((E:E<>"")*ROW(E:E))))
```

[image]

---

in old days it would be solved by generating it:

```
={""; INDEX("={"&TEXTJOIN("; ", 1, "IMPORTRANGE("""&
 FILTER(E2:E, E2:E<>"")&""", """&FILTER(F2:F, F2:F<>"")&""")")&"}")}
```

[image]

Comment: Without a doubt, you've participated in those competitions. `Reduce` is just flowing.

Answer (score 4):

`REDUCE` accepts and returns arrays. We can use it to stack ranges. [`INDEX/COUNTA`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/) can be used to get the range needed without blanks. `OFFSET` can be used to get the next column's value.

```
=QUERY(
  REDUCE(
    {"Id","Amount"},
    E2:INDEX(E2:E,COUNTA(E2:E)),
    LAMBDA(
      a,e,
      {a;IMPORTRANGE(e,OFFSET(e,0,1))}
    )
  ),
  "Select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1",
  1
)
```

Comment: Does this have a name `E2:INDEX...`? @Themaster

Comment: @Osm `:` is range operator(a operator like `+`). It doesn't have to be `INDEX`. You can join any valid range from any range returning formulas(eg:`OFFSET`,`INDIRECT`,etc).

Comment: @Osm [Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculation-operators-and-precedence-in-excel-48be406d-4975-4d31-b2b8-7af9e0e2878a)

Comment: Great answer. I need to learn more about reduce (as I said earlier). I gave player() the check since she posted first. Thanks again...